# iRate Compile Error with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, irate

I am using the latest version of iRate with Swift, trying to compile my project for App Store submission.

iRate installation [isn't very complicated](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate) - you drag two (optionally 3) files into your Project and then include the `iRate.h` file in a bridging header.

However, when I go to compile, I'm getting a `Apple LLVM 6.0 Error` about compiling the `iRate.m` file.

I've checked and the `iRate.m` ***is*** assigned to my project under Target Membership.

Can anyone please help?

```
CompileC /Users/Dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DA-hizhzqckxkpqjxafuimctebfhwho/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/DA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/DA.build/Release-iphoneos/DA.build/Objects-normal/armv7/iRate.o DA/iRate.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd "/Users/Dan/Projects/learn/DA"
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/Dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -fprofile-instr-use=/Users/Dan/Projects/learn/DA/OptimizationProfiles/DA.profdata -miphoneos-version-min=8.1 -iquote /Users/Dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DA-hizhzqckxkpqjxafuimctebfhwho/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/DA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/DA.build/Release-iphoneos/DA.build/DA-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/Dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DA-hizhzqckxkpqjxafuimctebfhwho/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/DA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/DA.build/Release-iphoneos/DA.build/DA-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/Dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DA-hizhzqckxkpqjxafuimctebfhwho/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/DA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/DA.build/Release-iphoneos/DA.build/DA-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay /Users/Dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DA-hizhzqckxkpqjxafuimctebfhwho/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/DA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/DA.build/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote /Users/Dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DA-hizhzqckxkpqjxafuimctebfhwho/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/DA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/DA.build/Release-iphoneos/DA.build/DA-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/Dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DA-hizhzqckxkpqjxafuimctebfhwho/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/DA/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/Dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DA-hizhzqckxkpqjxafuimctebfhwho/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/DA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/DA.build/Release-iphoneos/DA.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/Dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DA-hizhzqckxkpqjxafuimctebfhwho/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/DA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/DA.build/Release-iphoneos/DA.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/Dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DA-hizhzqckxkpqjxafuimctebfhwho/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/DA/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/Dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DA-hizhzqckxkpqjxafuimctebfhwho/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/DA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/DA.build/Release-iphoneos/DA.build/Objects-normal/armv7/iRate.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/Dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DA-hizhzqckxkpqjxafuimctebfhwho/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/DA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/DA.build/Release-iphoneos/DA.build/Objects-normal/armv7/iRate.dia -c /Users/Dan/Projects/learn/DA/DA/iRate.m -o /Users/Dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DA-hizhzqckxkpqjxafuimctebfhwho/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/DA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/DA.build/Release-iphoneos/DA.build/Objects-normal/armv7/iRate.o
error: Could not read profile: No such file or directory
1 error generated.
```

Comment: what kind of error are you seeing?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann - the full text of the error is included in the post.

Comment: thanks for editing your question to show the error.  :-)

Comment: Does a file exist at "`/Users/Dan/Projects/learn/DA/OptimizationProfiles/DA.profdata`"?

Comment: :) I thought that was always what Xcode says with the LLVM error

Comment: Perhaps you could post the error alone, the compiler line is 4200+ characters long! Making the error easier to see may help to get answers.

Comment: why not go into your project settings and remove the setting that refers to "`/Users/Dan/Projects/learn/DA/OptimizationProfiles/DA.profdata`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Michael Dautermann, removing the reference under the `Optimization Profile File` key found in `Xcode > Project > Build Settings` under the `Apple LLVM 6.0 - Code Generation` section.

I am new to Xcode and, at one point, had selected `Product > Perform Action > Generate Optimization Profile` menu option.

While I ended up aborting (read: I never finished generating the optimization profile), it apparently populated the `Optimization Profile File` key, which caused my error when I went to Archive.